# How to set model in collection with index backbone js

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js, collections

I have a collection of models. When i update one of the model i need to to set it in the collection.
I could get the oldModel and it's index but how can i set the returned one  (model) into the collection in the index desired.
I need something like this `regionProofsView.collection.models.set(index,model)` .

This is my code:

```
       myView.on("childview:model:update", function(childView, id) {
                var fetchingModel = VialinkSignManager.request("model:update", id);
                    $.when(fetchingModel).done(function(model) {
                    var oldModel=myView.collection.get(id);
                    var index=regionProofsView.collection.models.indexOf(oldProof);
                    // here i need to set the model into the collection
                    myView.render();
                    });
          });
```

Comment: Why not use the built in `fetch`, `save` etc to interact with the backend so that you won't even have to handle stuff like this..?

Answer (score 0):

You just want to replace the old model with the new model right? Backbone already tries to take care of this for you. Assuming you haven't changed the id, and the old model id = new model id, then all you have to do is call `collection.set(model)`. It will search the collection for a model with the same id and from http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set

> if the model is already in the collection its attributes will be merged;

Answer (score 0):

After research in the backbone documentation I've find this method as a solution.
After getting the oldModel and it's index I remove it and add in its index the new model:

```js
myView.on("childview:model:update", function(childView, id) {
      var fetchingModel = VialinkSignManager.request("model:update", id);
      $.when(fetchingModel).done(function(model) {
        var oldModel = myView.collection.get(id);
        var index = myView.collection.models.indexOf(oldModel);
        myView.collection.remove(oldModel);
        myView.collection.add(model, {
          at: index
        });
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you listen to the change event? The change event is triggered when the model changes.

```
 this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', view.doSomething);
```

Comment: the problem is that the chanbges are on the chidview not in the collection

Comment: Let me understand a little your architecture. You have a collection, and for each item in the collection you create a child view. When you change something in the child view, you want to have that change also in the collection. Is this your story?